# domain does not have ping in CentOS VPS

Tags: centos, vps, ping

I have a VPS with CentOS 6.x, DirectAdmin control panel, and CSF.
There are about 40 domains on it, but one of them did not load since yesterday (**itgates.ir**).
When I ping this domain, is there not any response. Its files are ok, and I don't know what's ther problem for!
All other domains are working well...
What is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heartbleed: are services other than HTTPS affected?](http://serverfault.com/questions/587433/heartbleed-are-services-other-than-https-affected)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this domain name has expired. According to the whois for the domain -

```
nserver:    ns1.parniaweb.net
nserver:    ns2.parniaweb.net
last-updated:   2014-04-07
expire-date:    2014-04-04
```

Interestingly the whois records show the nameservers as being ns[1,2].parniaweb.net, which are responding with an IP address, so the ISP is answering correctly for the domains - its just that no one knows to look to the ISP's nameservers.

(I can confirm that the TLD root nameservers are not carrying the NS records, so at a guess the domain name is suspended but can be paid for and fixed - I have no specific knowledge of .ir domains though)