# debian wheezy, heartbleed, openssl refuses to update

Tags: apt, openssl, debian-wheezy, heartbleed

I am having a strange problem, my system is exposed to heartbleed, and I am trying to fix it by using:
`apt-get clean`,
`apt-get update`
and
`apt-get upgrade openssl`

but the response is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
openssl is already the newest version.
The following packages have been kept back:
  libncurses5 libncursesw5 libssl-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

my openssl version is:
`openssl version -a`

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1f-dev xx XXX xxxx
built on: Mon Dec 23 14:23:57 UTC 2013
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(8x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

`openssl version -b`

```
built on: Mon Dec 23 14:23:57 UTC 2013
```

I had thought that the problem is in the sources list and here is my sources list:

```
#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib

#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib

#deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib
deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy main

deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

you can see the old ones in comment, but updating and trying to upgrade even with `apt-get upgrade` make no progress.

My serevr is on rackspace if it's somehow relevant...

I really don't know what to do, please help me.

Comment: yes I had tried...

Comment: I'm no debian guru, but if I correctly understand [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/587419/55514), Wheezy should be on 1.0.1e.  Have you perchance installed your own version of OpenSSL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks all for your efforts, here is how I had solved it:
apparently my openssl was from a test package instead of stable one. so the aptitude always thought the package is up to date.

in order to fix it I had run the next commands:
`apt-get install openssl=1.0.1a-2+deb7u7`
`apt-get install libssl1.0.0=1.0.1e-2+deb7u7`

it forced debian to install this packages with the exact version.
and now it works

Comment: I'll take that as a resounding "*yes*" to my question above, then!  Thank you for coming back and posting a cogent answer to your own question; this may help others in future.  Don't forget to accept it by clicking the tick outline next to it, once the site will permit that.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
apt-get install openssl
```

That should force Debian reinstalling/upgrading only the OpenSSL again. See what version it installs.