# Heartbleed - Centos 6.5, Apache - should I recreate pair of default certificate and key

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, centos6, heartbleed

I am using Centos 6.5, Apache 2.2.15 with SSL. Due to heartbleed I have updated openssl to release 16.el6_5.7 and I have restarted the httpd service.
I am using default Apache certificate and key:

*/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt

/etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key*

So my question is: after updating openssl should I create new pair of certificate and key or is it safe to use default?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the certs and keys which were made with the old openssl version **as soon as possible.** And read the [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/587329/heartbleed-what-is-it-and-what-are-options-to-mitigate-it) mentioned by MadHatter

Comment: Ok, thank you. For now it is not production server. I have it for my personal usage. I read the thread mentioned by MadHatter.