# Heartbleed, which specific services must be restarted?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, openssl, heartbleed

Trying to figure out exactly what services should be restarted after [patching openssl](https://serverfault.com/questions/587329/heartbleed-what-is-it-and-what-are-options-to-mitigate-it) against Heartbleed. At least one post mentions restarting:

> sshd, apache, nginx, postfix, dovecot, courier, pure-ftpd, bind, mysql

- Is there a command that can be run to see what running services are
  dependent on openssl?
- Is there a command to run against apache/nginx to see if the patch is active so the service doesn't need to be restarted?
- Should we just schedule downtime and reboot
  every server entirely?

EDIT: [This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/587324/heartbleed-how-to-reliably-and-portably-check-the-openssl-version) suggests using: `lsof -n | grep ssl | grep DEL` to display processes still using the old version of OpenSSL marked for deletion

Comment: Have you tried it - it certainly showed plenty of binaries using the old version for me on CentOS earlier.

Comment: Re: the `lsof` trick, it doesn't matter if the version number of the library changed: When the `.so` file is replaced the old inode becomes unlinked (`DEL`eted, in the lsof list). The file is not rewritten in place by any package manager or `install` program that I'm aware of.

Comment: @xref It is possible that there's an upgrade process *I'm not aware of* that rewrites the file in place (in which case you have a valid concern -- if you're worried about that just leave off the `|grep DEL` bit and work from the full list)

Answer (score 8):

As a general rule when mitigating a major vulnerability in a library which is used by many programs: **rebooting your server is the easiest way to ensure you've restarted every affected program, and that nothing is using the old (vulnerable) code**.

You should not fear rebooting your systems (you should be doing it pretty regularly when you install patches anyway!) - regularly rebooting your servers means you can be confident they will come back up without a problem, and if you design your environment for proper fault tolerance a reboot does not mean an outage. (For that matter even if your environment ISN'T fault-tolerant, we're talking maybe 10 minutes - a tiny outage considering the scale of the security problem we're talking about with heartbleed...)

---

If for some reason you can't reboot you can use `lsof` to determine what programs are running which are using the OpenSSL library: `sudo lsof -n | grep ssl`

To find ones using the OLD (deleted) library, you can do `sudo lsof -n | grep ssl | grep DEL`.

Each affected program will need to be restarted using whatever procedure is appropriate for that program.

Comment: As an additional note, any program which is *statically linked* against OpenSSL will need to be *recompiled and restarted* to address the vulnerability...