# How can I check if my embedded Linux's SSL is not affected by heartbleed, without relying on the version number?

Tags: security, openssl, gateway, heartbleed

There are a lot of embedded Linux device that are built on Linux, that are used exactly for security purposes, like gateways, if I check OpenSSL I get:

```
openssl version -a
```

gets -»

```
OpenSSL 1.0.0k 5 Feb 2013
```

But this maybe patched or merged and I don't have access to the sources, how can I check that my system is not vulnerable without relying on `openssl version -a`

Comment: SSH is not affected, if you mean SSL, there is a topic with 5 answers which explains how to check it.

Comment: @NickW SSH doesn't use SSL, still there could be issues with `https`  and VPNs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heartbleed: are services other than HTTPS affected?](http://serverfault.com/questions/587433/heartbleed-are-services-other-than-https-affected)

Comment: @Jacob Please read the body, I want to know how if its affected without relying on the version number...

Comment: You might also want to check this: http://serverfault.com/questions/587324/heartbleed-how-to-reliably-and-portably-check-the-openssl-version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [perl script](https://github.com/noxxi/p5-scripts/blob/master/check-ssl-heartbleed.pl) that allows you to check our own services. There are also [online](http://possible.lv/tools/hb/) tools. [One more](http://filippo.io/Heartbleed/).

Answer (score 1):

Qualys SSL Labs has a very good SSL Test, which features Heartbleed tests as well, and generally servers as a good point in testing your own SSL Infrastructure for stuff like Forward Secrecy, BEAST Attacks, weak protocols and whatnot. And it's free.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/